# Does something like binaryWriter.Write((byte)67) involve a runtime cast?

Tags: c#, casting

Since there isn't a suffix to indicate a byte literal and you have to use a cast (or assign to a byte variable), I'm using the following code to ensure that the Write(byte) overload is used instead of Write(int):

```
binaryWriter.Write((byte)67)
```

And I was wondering if the compiled code would actually perform that cast at runtime or if the compiled IL either has something equivalent to a suffix for byte literals or specifically states which overload of a method is used?

Comment: It just selects the overload.  The technical background is very deep and gets you into processor design, you can learn a lot more about it by googling "c integer promotion".  Applies to the C language and it is much better hidden in C# but the principles are the same.  Most glaring case of it not being hidden is having to use a cast to store the value of an expression back into a byte..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest you can do to answer such questions is look at IL code generated:

```
ldc.i4.s     67
callvirt     instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.BinaryWriter::Write(unsigned int8)
```

First pushes your literal to stack as int32 using short form (suitable for integers between -128 to 127). This is exactly what will happen if you just declare byte variable and use that. Don't let "as int32" confuse you - you cannot push single byte to stack, so it always pushes at least 4 bytes (ldc.i4 family of instructions).

Second calls correct overload.

Now what will happen if we won't cast to byte?

```
ldc.i4.s     67
callvirt     instance void [mscorlib]System.IO.BinaryWriter::Write(int32)
```

First instruction is exactly the same, and then just another overload is called.
So answer to your question is: no casts are performed, compiler just specifically states which overload to use.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if the compiled code would actually perform that cast
>   at runtime

No, it won't. For two overloads `M(int n)` and `M(byte b)`, `M(67)` always calls the former, according to C# language specification, chapter 7.5.3.2， since `67` is a `int` literal.

> if the compiled IL either has something equivalent to a suffix for
>   byte literals

No, there is no byte literals like `67L`/`67UL`/`67D`...

> specifically states which overload of a method is used

You can either use an explicit conversion (or assign it to a `byte` variable) like what you did in the question, or write an extension method to "rename" the original function like this:

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void WriteByte(this BinaryWriter writer, byte b)
    {
        writer.Write(b);
    }
}
```